# How many connections to maintain in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using the RabbitMQ java client.
My app has multiple exchanges and queues. Adopting something similar to the Pub/Sub model.

What is the best practice regarding connections?
Shall I have one connection per app?

I understand the channel model, and the thread (un)safety model. Just not sure if I should have multiple connections or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One connection per app is correct.

Within that connection, you will have many channels - where the actual work is done.

You can have hundreds or thousands of message producers and consumers (each on their on channel) inside a single connection.

If you start to see slowdown in your RMQ setup because you're dong too much work, look at clustering RMQ and/or standing up multiple instances of your app.

But you would still maintain 1 connection per app instance.

Comment: Great answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It will depends on the volumetry of messages you will have. If it really is huge, maybe 2 or 3 connections could do it, but one per application seems to be the best choice

Comment: My question was not regarding queues. It was regarding connections.

Comment: My bad, I meant connections

Comment: ok, thanks. But, can you explain, supply justifications supporting your claims?

Comment: The thing is, if you only have one open connection:  
- you'll better control the flow of messages  
- you won't ruin your network connection by being flooded by outgoing or incoming messages